# Dealing with an "Access to fetch blocked by CORS policy" exception in React app connecting to Azure Cosmos DB (SQL API)

Tags: reactjs, azure, cors, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am trying to create a very simple React, front-end application that will connect to Azure Cosmos DB and allow the user to perform simple tasks like search the database. I am using the SQL API of CosmosDB, not MongoDB, and am having trouble connecting my application to CosmosDB. As of right now, it is just a simple webpage with a connect button that, when clicked, attempts to create a database if it doesn't exist and then create a container in that db. My code looks like this (with the endpoint and key left out intentionally):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
const CosmosClient = require('@azure/cosmos').CosmosClient;

class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {    
      client : new CosmosClient({
        endpoint: "my-endpoint",
        key: "my-primary-key"
      }),
      databaseID : "My-db-name",
      containerID : "My-db-container"
    };
    this.connect = this.connect.bind(this);
    this.init = this.init.bind(this);
  }

  connect() {
    this.init(err => {
      console.error(err);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
      console.error(
        'Shutting down because there was an error setting up the database.'
      );
    });
  }

  async init() {
    const dbResponse = await this.state.client.databases.createIfNotExists({
        id: this.state.databaseID
    });
    const coResponse = await dbResponse.database.containers.createIfNotExists({
        id: this.state.containerID
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        </div>
        <button className="Connect-Button" onClick={this.connect}>
          Connect to Azure
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

When I click on the "Connect to Azure" button, I receive the following errors:

"Access to fetch at 'https://react-test-db.documents.azure.com/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled."

Along with: "GET https://react-test-db.documents.azure.com/ net::ERR_FAILED" and "TypeError: Failed to fetch"

I have tried to enable CORS like suggested in https://medium.com/@alexishevia/using-cors-in-express-cac7e29b005b, however that didn't seem to do anything.

In the Microsoft Azure Portal, there is a CORS tab that allows you to add domains to make cross-origin calls to your DB. However, localhost:3000/ is an "invalid origin" and is not allowed. Does that have something to do with it? Or is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: Can you try with “*” i.e. all domains?

Comment: Are you sure it's okay that your account key is revealed to users in the front-end? If that is the actual primary key, a user could create new containers with max RUs, causing actual financial damage. Or delete all the data etc.

Comment: You need to use `http://localhost:3000` rather than `localhost:3000/` — because an origin value must include the `http://` or `https://` protocol part, and must not include an path component (so, no trailing slash).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still facing this issue, Microsoft has provided a solution. Simply go to your CosmosDB account page, in the right menu under "Settings" select the "CORS" option or blade and put the url from where your app is running into the "Allowed Origins" text field.
If you are running from localhost and ip address constantly changes, for development purposes you can use "*" temporarily as shown in below image:

[image: CosmosDB CORS fix]

Re-start your app and it should stop the CORS erros.

Answer (score 0):

Other than setting up the CORS policy on the CosmosDB CORS blade in Azure portal, as it explained above - and in more details here:
[Configure Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/how-to-configure-cross-origin-resource-sharing). Pay attention to the specific instruction about the use of `@azure/cosmos` library from a browser:

> Today, the Azure Cosmos DB JavaScript library only has the CommonJS version of the library shipped with its package. To use this library from the browser, you have to use a tool such as Rollup or Webpack to create a browser compatible library. Certain Node.js libraries should have browser mocks for them. The following is an example of a webpack config file that has the necessary mock settings.

You have a detailed instructions of how to make the package work from a browser on the same page, here:

[Using the Azure Cosmos DB JavaScript library from a browser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/how-to-configure-cross-origin-resource-sharing#using-the-azure-cosmos-db-javascript-library-from-a-browser)

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried using your machine's IP address instead of localhost? If you have a UNIX like machine the IP address can be found from the terminal using `ifconfig` command.

Comment: I have not. How does one switch a web app from localhost to my machine's IP address? (Usually I just run npm start and it opens in localhost)